# Ordering of Preprocessor statement gives me warning?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a code as following

**ApplicationSetting.h**

FOUNDATION_EXPORT BOOL *const TEST_MODE;

**ApplicationSetting.m**

#ifdef DEBUG
BOOL *const TEST_MODE = YES;
 #else
BOOL *const TEST_MODE = NO;
 #endif

The above .m file's code gives me this warning

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'BOOL *const' 
(aka 'signed char *const') with an expression of type 'signed char';
```

But, if I change it to be come like this

#ifdef DEBUG
BOOL *const TEST_MODE = NO;
 #else
BOOL *const TEST_MODE = YES;
 #endif

It works just fine without any warning.

Do you have any idea how could this happens?

Comment: It's not all pointers in Obj-C...  No need to declare the boolean flag as a pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really meant to write a value:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const BOOL TEST_MODE;
```

…`BOOL` is not an objc object, it is a `signed char`.

as far as the error, the compiler complains because you are assigning numeric values to the pointer value -- where only `0` (aka `NULL`) is acceptable to the compiler, and any other number (`YES` is `1`) will produce the error/warning.

P.S. Just use `bool`.

Comment: Thank Justin, but, bool or BOOL gives me the same result. Is there any other way around to have a constant boolean beside of using macro?

Comment: @Tar_Tw45 yes - use a constant *value*, not *pointer*. note the omission of the `*` in `const BOOL TEST_MODE`.

Comment: @Tar_Tw45 i've been working with these languages for many, many years -- i still make a good number of dumb mistakes, haha -- i use very high warning levels and the warnings will catch most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain in more detail:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion …

You tried to convert an integer value—a number—to a pointer. This can be done, but it's usually a bad idea and consequently requires a high level of explicitness. It's hard to do by accident (nowadays/on this compiler), and there are reasons for that.

> … initializing '`BOOL *const`' (aka '`signed char *const`') …

This is the type of variable you declared. As this part of the message explains, `BOOL` is also known as `signed char` (i.e., the one is `typedef`'d to the other).

`char` is the smallest of the integer types in C, so you've declared this variable to hold a pointer to an integer.

> … with an expression of type 'signed char';

The expression in this case is the initializer from your declaration. It's the part that you changed between the two versions of the declaration: `YES` in one case, `NO` in the other.

The Objective-C headers define `NO` as 0 and `YES` as 1, both cast to `BOOL` (which, as noted above, is defined as `signed char`).

So:

- Your initializer is a `BOOL` value (as justin rightly pointed out, `BOOL` with no `*`), which is an integer.
- Your variable holds a `BOOL *`—a pointer.
- The compiler will not let this fly without you being very explicit that this is something you mean to do.
- Even if you did convince the compiler to go along with this, it would not be correct code.

As justin already established, you should leave out the `*`. This will declare the variable as holding a `BOOL` value, not a pointer.

I also second his suggestion of using `bool` instead. Unlike `BOOL`, a `bool` can never be any value except `true` (1) or `false` (0), unless you try *very* hard.